# Authenticate & Authorize jax-rs rest services

Tags: java, spring, rest, restful-authentication

I have a web application and I want to make an Android version, so user can access the application via web (browser) or via android. My web application i build using Spring, Struts, Hibernate and I've create rest service using jax-rs. But i confuse how to authenticate and authorizing android request. I mean, example when user from android accessing rest service XYZ, i confuse how to check if android user has login and has authorizing to access the function in my rest service. User account and user authorize function i store on database. And i confuse how to save user log when user accessing application via android. i confuse how to get current user so i can create log on my web application. How can i solve this,

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

if you want to some low level security than just set one header in request

for Ex. **Requested_With** : **Android**
and check using [@HeaderParam](http://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-rs/get-http-header-in-jax-rs/) in your Java code and verify  if header found which is set by you than go ahead.